# Overriding unwanted page size in SOLR

Tags: solr

I have a web application that uses SOLR as backend search service.

All requests that control searches are GET requests: user does something (type something, choose a page size, a sort critera) and, after pressing the search button, a corresponding servlet on the web app calls SOLR.

Now, the parameters sent to my servlet are exposed in the browser address bar; this is good because

1) each page on the webapp can be stored as permalink
2) the search can be controlled by changing directly the URL

On top of that, for a specific parameter, the page size, I would like to impose some constraint. I mean: if the select menu on the web app proposes 3 choices (5,10,15) I don't want other values.

Now, I know I can do that in my servlet but I was wondering if it is possible on SOLR side too...local params? don't know.

Briefly: the "rows" parameters on SOLR must be 5,10 or 20: if a value > 20 comes then 20 is applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within Solr SearchHandlers you can predefine some configuration settings as outlined in the [Configuration](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SearchHandler#Configuration) section. This allows you to set the following parameter behaviors

> - **defaults** - provides default param values that will be used if the param does not have a value specified at request time.
> - **appends** - provides param values that will be used in addition to any values specified at request time (or as defaults.
> - **invariants** - provides param values that will be used in spite of any values provided at request time. They are a way of letting the Solr maintainer lock down the options available to Solr clients. Any params values specified here are used regardless of what values may be specified in either the query, the "defaults", or the "appends" params.

However, these three options, do not provide for the specific behavior of limiting the rows value to 20 like you are seeking. I believe the only way to limit this within Solr would be to create a custom Request Handler and plug that into Solr. The article - [Developing a Request Handler for Solr](http://www.searchbox.com/developing-a-request-handler-for-solr/) provides a good overview of the steps needed to create you own Request Handler.